# How to read the SqlDataAdapter command text in clean

Tags: c#, asp.net, parameters, sqldataadapter

this is my image: [How to read the SqlDataAdapter command text in clean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSlhD.png)

May i know how to read the SqlDataAdapter command text in clean text.
Example:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_Video WHERE VideoName=@VideoName
```

I would like to know the parameter value I just pass in plain text, because I want to stored the whole SQL stament with parameter value into log file table. The purpose I use parameter is because I would like to avoid SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

here is my method I use to get data from a MySQL database. 
ex) string q = "SELECT ID FROM Users WHERE Username=chris";
    string id = dbGetData(q); //users id

```
 public static String dbGetData(String q)
    {
        openConnection(); //opens connection if closed
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, connection);
            return cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, chris, thank you for your answer. Didn't this SQL statement is vulnerable to SQL injection attack?

Comment: @TiongGor oh i am not sure. It would be good if someone can let me know if this is true

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a built-in method for this, however the following helper function will serve the purpose:

```
private static string GetSqlCommandTextForLogs(SqlCommand cmd)
{
    string text = cmd.CommandText;
    foreach (SqlParameter parameter in cmd.Parameters)
    {
        text = text.Replace("@"+parameter.ParameterName, parameter.Value.ToString());
    }
    return text;
}
```

The `SelectCommand` property on `SqlDataAdapter` is of type `SqlCommand` and can be passed into such a helper to get the log-appropriate text you are seeking.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the [SqlCommandBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) and get the CommandText off the commands.

Example:

```
   using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("YOUR CONNECTION"))
   {
      connection.Open();
      SqlDataAdapter thisAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ID from SOMETABLE", connection);

      SqlCommandBuilder thisBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(thisAdapter);

      Console.WriteLine("SQL SELECT Command is:\n{0}\n", thisAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandText);

      SqlCommand updateCommand = thisBuilder.GetUpdateCommand();
      Console.WriteLine("SQL UPDATE Command is:\n{0}\n", updateCommand.CommandText);

      SqlCommand insertCommand = thisBuilder.GetInsertCommand();
      Console.WriteLine("SQL INSERT Command is:\n{0}\n", insertCommand.CommandText);

      SqlCommand deleteCommand = thisBuilder.GetDeleteCommand();
      Console.WriteLine("SQL DELETE Command is:\n{0}", deleteCommand.CommandText);
   }
```